# ¿Como obtener los datos duplicados de un arreglo con reduce?

Tags: javascript, reduce

Dado este arreglo quisiera obtener los datos duplicados utilizando reduce.

```
const frutas = ['platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'higo' ];
```

resultado: `['platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'platano' ]`

Ya que los datos no duplicados si los puede acceder aplicando el siguiente codigo:

```
let resultado = frutas.reduce((a,f) => {
    if(a.indexOf(f) === -1){
     a.push(f)
    }
   return a
},[])
```

resultado: `['platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'higo']`

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿y si se repiten más de una vez? Es decir, `platano` se repite 3 veces, ¿El array de salida debe tener uno o dos platanos?

Comment: Hola, solo se tiene que imprimir 1 solo valor, no importa si tiene más de 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, agrego todos los elementos que se repiten más de una vez con un `filter`. En este punto, todos los elementos repetidos estarán en el resultado del `filter`, pero como pueden haber elementos que se repiten más de dos veces, utilizo `Set` para dejar solo una instancia de cada elemento.

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional en código:

```js
const frutas = ['platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'higo' ];

let repetidos = frutas.filter((item, index) => frutas.indexOf(item) !== index) 
repetidos = [...new Set(repetidos)]
console.log(repetidos);
```

Hacerlo con reduce es equivalente a hacerlo con filter, pero de igual forma te adjunto la respuesta:

```js
const frutas = ['platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'manzana', 'platano', 'cereza', 'naranja', 'higo' ];

let repetidos = frutas.reduce((a,e,i) =>{
  if(frutas.indexOf(e) !== i)
    if(!a.includes(e))
      a.push(e)
  return a
},[]) 
console.log(repetidos);
```